# How can I install 1.9.3 version of ruby on Mac?

Tags: ruby, xcode, openssl, rvm

I use `rvm install 1.9.3` to instal ruby, but I've got the following error.

```
Xcode version older than 4.6.2 installed, download and install newer version from:

    http://connect.apple.com

After installation open Xcode, go to Downloads and install Command Line Tools.

Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-1.9.3-p551', please read /Users/.rvm/log/1605112932_ruby-1.9.3-p551/update_system.log Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

My Xcode version is

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
 Xcode 12.1 
Build version 12A7403
```

So, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569954/trouble-installing-ruby-1-9-3-on-mac-osx-10-9-4) and tried

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

But got the same mistake. Then I tried

```
rvm pkg install openssl
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 CPP=/usr/local/bin/cpp-4.2 CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.2  rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

But when I  use **rvm pkg install openssl** got

```
Error running '__rvm_make install',
please read /Users/.rvm/log/1605114992/openssl_make.install.log
```

This file is really huge, but the beginning is

```
[2020-11-11 20:18:55] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1i
GEM_HOME=/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin:/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global/bin:/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648:/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global
command(2): __rvm_make install
+ make install
making all in crypto...
making all in crypto/objects...
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
making all in crypto/md4...
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

And the end of the file is

```
installing man3/err.3
installing man3/evp.3
installing man3/hmac.3
/bin/sh: /Users/.rvm/usr/ssl/man/man3/hmac.3: Too many levels of symbolic links
make: *** [install_docs] Error 1
+ return 2
```

And how to fix that I couldn't find. Can somebody help me?

Comment: please read /Users/ashymanovich/.rvm/log/1605114992/openssl_make.install.log and paste its content there

Comment: @DNNX this file is really huge, but I pasted the beginning and the end of this file.

Comment: For legacy projects that require Ruby 1.9.3 you should consider using a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Support for Ruby 1.9.3 ended in February 2015, over five and a half years ago, it was released in 2011, nine years ago; The Ruby 1.9 series was released in 2007, thirteen years ago. Ruby 1.9.3 does not support getting compiled with Clang, and it probably can't be compiled with modern versions of GCC either. It also cannot be linked against current versions of OpenSSL.

Getting Ruby 1.9.3 to compile on a current platform by hunting each and every one of the invariably dozens of errors will probably be very tedious.

If you want to compile software that is *that* old, the easiest way is to do that, is to do it on the OS version that it was *actually* tested on. In your case, that would probably be MacOS X 10.7 "Lion".